# Glass and Transparency - Wine Bottle

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, glass, reflection

I have been following a wine bottle tutorial on skillshare.
My problem is that a mesh liquid inside and bottle have this weird reflection using Cycles.

I already flipped normals, merged by distance, increased light bounces, made sure mesh is not overlapping. Nothing seems to work.

Google Drive link to blender file and more photos.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zf8fPBxw2mVJyfQd8w1b25cv3i8bpYPC?usp=drive_link

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "weird reflection"? Could you please be more precise?

Comment: If you don't want the weird reflection, delete the "Studio" backdrop because that's the object that is reflected.